# Azure policy for VM Sku based on Vm Name

Tags: azure-policy

I am trying to write my first Azure Policy.

I want it to audit my virtual machines, where the name ends with -tr-sa-vm, to see if they are within the allowed vmSKUs.
I thought the below would work, but it says Compliant 100% 0 out of 0.
Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "TR - Allowed VM Sizes",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Compute",
      "createdBy": "0dcf9e6c-b717-485b-8704-a0695cd10be7",
      "createdOn": "2020-04-29T19:38:39.486075Z",
      "updatedBy": null,
      "updatedOn": null
    },
    "parameters": {
      "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Allowed SKUs",
          "description": "The list of SKUs that can be specified for TR virtual machines.",
          "strongType": "vmSKUs"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "like": "*-tr-sa-vm"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name",
              "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/c8387722-df99-4ac4-9e19-682e684b048d/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/44fd80d7-569a-416e-92ee-be2a5b56e9fd",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "44fd80d7-569a-416e-92ee-be2a5b56e9fd"
}
```

Expected result:
Lets say I have 200 Virtual Machines, 100 of those have a name that ends with -tr-sa-vm
If there are currently 30 of those 100, which do not have an allowed sku.name, then I would expect to see it say 30 out of 100 are not compliant.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that policy might be still in Compliance state of "**Not started**". Did you check the Compliance state?
[image]
A policy that is newly assigned to a scope takes around 30 minutes for the assignment to be applied to the defined scope. Once it's applied, the evaluation cycle begins for resources within that scope against the newly assigned policy and depending on the effects used by the policy, resources are marked as **Compliant** or **Non-compliant**.

I tried the same policy and it works for me.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right it does work, I was mistaken. Do you know how I can change it so that the VM Name is an OR statement? I was it to be Name is like "*-tr-sa-vm" OR "*-sa"

Comment: You can use "anyOf" operator for this condition.